# shared pointers in main function, factory

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a better way of writing this code in a more experienced/c++17 way.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //I recieve a std::string str as input here
    manager mgr;
    auto baseptr = ( (str == "doA") ? std::make_shared<myclass>(mgr): 
                                          std::make_shared<otherclass>(mgr));

}
```

Comment: Yes, when using `? :` you should have compatible types on both sides of the `:`.

Comment: Code that makes compile-time decisions, like choosing a type, based on runtime values is always a bit clunky. It's a good idea to replace "stringly typed" things with strongly typed things though, so translating from strings to an enum as a first step is good.

Comment: @molbdnilo could you put in an example.

Comment: @newbie Do you have more tha these two classes?

Comment: @TedLyngmo three classes only. I plan to add one more to the above code.

Comment: @newbie Ok, I added something that can be easily extended to cover _many_ cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the conditional operator (`<cond> ? <true result> : <false result>`) like that since the `true` result and `false` result must be of compatible types.

Since you only have two classes, you could just do this:
(*All `manager` declarations below may need to be `const` depending on the usage.*)

```
#include <memory>
#include <string_view>

auto factory(const std::string_view& str, manager& mgr) {
    std::shared_ptr<base> retval;

    if(str == "doA") retval = std::make_shared<myclass>(mgr);
    else             retval = std::make_shared<otherclass>(mgr);

    return retval;
}
```

---

If you want to add a lot of *`std::string`-to-class* mappings, you could use a `std::unordered_map` and store factory functors in it:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

auto factory(const std::string_view& str, manager& mgr) {   
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::shared_ptr<base>(*)(manager&)> fact{
        {"doA", [](manager& mgr)->std::shared_ptr<base>{ return std::make_shared<myclass1>(mgr); }},
        {"foo", [](manager& mgr)->std::shared_ptr<base>{ return std::make_shared<myclass2>(mgr); }},
        {"bar", [](manager& mgr)->std::shared_ptr<base>{ return std::make_shared<myclass3>(mgr); }},
    };

    std::shared_ptr<base> baseptr;

    if(auto it = fact.find(str); it != fact.end())
        baseptr = it->second(mgr);
    else
        baseptr = std::make_shared<otherclass>(mgr); // fallback if "str" not found in map

    return baseptr;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oKhnsG)